# How to tell exactly how long it takes to finish a DAG in Airflow (SLA) and how to implement an alert for this

Tags: airflow

I am a beginner in Airflow and I have a quick question. So in Airflow, we know when the DAG is scheduled but I am not sure how to tell how long it exactly takes to finish. Also, if a job finished in 30 minutes and the SLA is set to 1 hour...is there any way we can be alerted/notified that an hour has past and its not complete and how do you implement this on Airflow.

Comment: Airflow supports email notifications on SLA miss. I guess if that's not an ok way to get notified you can define a callback function for the parameter `sla_miss_callback` as the [docs](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/1.10.10/concepts.html?highlight=slas#slas) specify

Comment: Thank you for this. In addition to what I mentioned. In Airflow, how do we know it started on time? How do we know it completed on time? How can we be notified it is running long? And how can we know if it failed?

Comment: You can access the DAG object programmatically, but it's probably better if you ask a new question for that instead of adding secondary questions in comments

Comment: Also, I figured I'd just move my comment to an answer since it seems it helped. If that was not the case (regarding the question) let me know so that I can delete the answer

Answer (score 0):

Airflow supports email notifications on SLA miss. I guess if that's not an ok way to get notified you can define a callback function for the parameter `sla_miss_callback` as the [docs](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/1.10.10/concepts.html?highlight=slas#slas) specify.